# How to open a link to a new tab using php functions

Tags: html

I am currently working on a small project and i want to know do i open the link menu to a new tab. Here is the php function am working on:

```
<li>
  <a href="<?php echo $menu->url, '_blank'; ?>">
    <i class="<?php echo $menu->classes['0']; ?>"></i>
     <?php echo $menu->title; ?>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: That is not a "php" function. It's a html function

Comment: Just use `target="_blank"` in anchor tag

Answer (score 4):

Specify the `target` attribute:

```
<a href="<?php echo $menu->url; ?>" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to open a new tab in php because php code runs on the server side and the web browser is on the client side.

To create an anchor tag that opens in a new tab, you can add the attribute `target="_blank"` for example:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code modified. you can use this

```
<li>
 <a href="<?php echo $menu->url; ?>" target='_blank'>
  <i class="<?php echo $menu->classes['0']; ?>"></i>
  <?php echo $menu->title; ?>
 </a>
</li>
```